# Determine if Type is a pointer in a template function

Tags: c++, templates

If I have a template function, for example like this:

```
template<typename T>
void func(const std::vector<T>& v)
```

Is there any way I can determine within the function whether T is a pointer, or would I have to use another template function for this, ie:

```
template<typename T>
void func(const std::vector<T*>& v)
```

Thanks

Comment: If, like me, you want to use a function that may be different depending on whether `T` is a pointer or not, you may find this answer very useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466620/c-template-specialization-calling-methods-on-types-that-could-be-pointers-or/14466705

Answer (score 100):

Indeed, templates can do that, with partial template specialization:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_pointer { static const bool value = false; };

template<typename T>
struct is_pointer<T*> { static const bool value = true; };

template<typename T>
void func(const std::vector<T>& v) {
    std::cout << "is it a pointer? " << is_pointer<T>::value << std::endl;
}
```

If in the function you do things only valid to pointers, you better use the method of a separate function though, since the compiler type-checks the function as a whole.

You should, however, use boost for this, it includes that too: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_pointer.html

Comment: What a lonely little answer you've got here. :)

Comment: @GMan haha :) How did you hit this old answer of me xD

Comment: @Johannes: Meh, I remembered you were abnormally high on the `templates` tag top rep. list, so I wanted to see why. :)

Comment: +1 Some answers never get old, Johannes. This is one such answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig Actually this answer did get old, because for C++ 11 this other answer is better http://stackoverflow.com/a/15974269/55721

Answer (score 69):

C++ 11 has a nice little pointer check function built in: `std::is_pointer<T>::value`

This returns a boolean `bool` value.

From 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A {};

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_pointer<A>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_pointer<A*>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_pointer<float>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_pointer<int>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_pointer<int*>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_pointer<int**>::value << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From C++17, there is an even shorter built-in construct, `std::is_pointer_v<T>`:

```
#include <type_traits>
 
int main()
{
    class A {};
 
    static_assert(
           not std::is_pointer<A>::value
        && not std::is_pointer_v<A>); // equivalent to above, but shorter

    return 0;
}
```