# Templated class function T: How to find out if T is a pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

As a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301330/determine-if-type-is-a-pointer-in-a-template-function): I need to decide in a class function like this:

```
template< typename T > bool Class::Fun <T*> ( T& variable ) {...}
```

whether T is a pointer or not.

In the question cited above the answer was to use partial template specialization. As far as I've found out this is not possible for class functions. Is this true? If so, is there another way of finding out if T is a pointer?

Comment: @iammilind: You'll note that the question already linked to the question you've marked it a duplicate of and that it also was already stated there in what respect it is different. Please remove the "marked as duplicate".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No need to specialize member function. In that answer used stand-alone structure. You're still free to use it in class member functions.

```
// stand-alone helper struct
template<typename T>
struct is_pointer { static const bool value = false; };    
template<typename T>
struct is_pointer<T*> { static const bool value = true; };

// your class
class Class{
public:
 template<typename T>
 void Fun(T& variable) {
     std::cout << "is it a pointer? " << is_pointer<T>::value << std::endl;
 }
};
```

On the other hand, you could *overload* function:

```
class Class {
public:
 template<typename T>
 void Fun(T& variable) {
     std::cout << "is it not a pointer! " << std::endl;
 }
 template<typename T>
 void Fun(T*& variable) {
     std::cout << "is it a pointer! " << std::endl;
 }
};
```

Comment: You've shown two very good ways to achieve that. Unfortunately I have only one vote to give you. `:)`

Comment: Thank you for praise, but I'd say I've shown usual/standard ways to achieve that.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [boost::is_pointer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_pointer.html).

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Boost.TypeTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html), together with [Boost EnableIf](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html).