# C++ whether a template type is a pointer or not

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine if Type is a pointer in a template function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301330/determine-if-type-is-a-pointer-in-a-template-function)

I am looking for a method to determine whether a template is a pointer or not at compiling time. Because when T is not a pointer, the program will not compile as you cannot delete a normal type variable.

```
template <typename T>
void delete(T &aVar)
{
   // if T is a point
   delete aVar;
   aVar = 0;
   // if T is not a point, do nothing
}
```

---

Basically, I am learning to create a link list(not using the STL list) myself. And I tried to use template in my list so it can take any types. When the type is a pointer, I want to delete it (the keyword delete) automatically by the destructor.

The problem is, as writen above, when I use int rather than some pointer of a class in the list, VC2010 wont compile because you cannot delete an none pointer variable. So I am looking for a method, such as macro to deceide when delete aVar should be compiled or not according to the template type

Comment: Do you mean `operator delete` or `delete_something`? `delete` is a keyword.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Please use the "101010"-button or 4 space indent for your code to have it marked up as code. Like I just did for you :)

Comment: I don't see what this is a duplicate of? In any case, what might be required in this case is simply two overloads (one that does nothing for non-pointers). And perhaps the class is trying to do too much - after all perhaps I don't want the class to manage my pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a handy utility, but I think it's better just to get used to assigning `NULL` after using native `delete`.

To get a function that only is considered for modifiable pointer type arguments, use

```
template< typename T > // The compiler may substitute any T,
void delete_ref( T *&arg ); // but argument is still a pointer in any case.
```

To simply find out whether a type is a pointer, use `is_pointer` from `<type_traits>` in Boost, TR1, or C++0x.

Comment: Thanks for the is_pointer, I will try to overload my class and use is_pointer to determine which one to use, pointer one or not.

Comment: @HideTail: You shouldn't need to check anything. Overload resolution automatically determines which function to call. http://codepad.org/AgTVISzv

Answer (score 3):

How about having that function taking a T* instead of T?

Comment: +1, Or, for his purpose, a T*&