# C++ template specialization, calling methods on types that could be pointers or references unambiguously

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, reference, template-specialization

**Summary**

Is there a way to call a class method on a templated type that could be a pointer or a reference without knowing which and not get compiler/linker errors?

---

**Details**

I have a templated QuadTree implementation that can take any of the following non-trivial user-defined types:

```
//Abstract Base Class
a2de::Shape

//Derived Classes
a2de::Point
a2de::Line
a2de::Rectangle
a2de::Circle
a2de::Ellipse
a2de::Triangle
a2de::Arc
a2de::Spline
a2de::Sector
a2de::Polygon
```

But they could be a pointer OR a reference as they are all derived from a2de::Shape. So the specializations are declared as:

```
template class QuadTree<a2de::Shape&>;
//...similar for all derived types as references.

template class QuadTree<a2de::Shape*>;
//...similar for all derived types as pointers
```

The problem I am having is the ability to call a class method when the indirection (or lack thereof) is unknown and due to the templates, both sets of code are generated:

```
template<typename T>
bool QuadTree<T>::Add(T& elem) {

    //When elem of type T is expecting a pointer here
    //-> notation fails to compile where T is a reference i.e.:
    //template class QuadTree<a2de::Shape&>
    //with "pointer to reference is illegal"

    if(elem->Intersects(_bounds) == false) return false;

    //...
}
```

If I change the above line to use the . (dot) notation:

```
template<typename T>
bool QuadTree<T>::Add(T& elem) {

    //When elem of type T is expecting a reference here
    //. (dot) notation fails to compile where T is a pointer i.e.:
    //template class QuadTree<a2de::Shape*>
    //with "pointer to reference is illegal"

    if(elem.Intersects(_bounds) == false) return false;

    //...

}
```

If I remove the reference-based types in favor of the pointer-based types (including in the declaration and usage of the Quadtree class) I get the error `left of .<function-name> must have class/struct/union`.

If I remove the pointer-based type in favor of the reference-based types (including in the declaration and usage of the Quadtree class) I get the aforementioned `reference to pointer is illegal` again.

compiler: VS2010-SP1

Comment: let me try to understand: you are looking for a syntactic way to generalize `.` and `->`? also, why not just using `shared_ptr`?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Small overloaded functions can be used to turn *reference* into *pointer*:

```
template<typename T>
T * ptr(T & obj) { return &obj; } //turn reference into pointer!

template<typename T>
T * ptr(T * obj) { return obj; } //obj is already pointer, return it!
```

Now instead of doing this:

```
 if(elem->Intersects(_bounds) == false) return false;
 if(elem.Intersects(_bounds) == false) return false;
```

Do this:

```
 if( ptr(elem)->Intersects(_bounds) == false) return false;
```

If `elem` is a reference, the first overload `ptr` will be selected, else the second will be selected. Both returns *pointer*, which means irrespective of what `elem` is in your code, the expression `ptr(elem)` will always be a *pointer* which you can use to invoke the member functions, as shown above.

Since `ptr(elem)` is pointer, which means checking it for `nullptr` be good idea:

```
 if( ptr(elem) && (ptr(elem)->Intersects(_bounds) == false)) return false;
```

Comment: very nice. question: wouldn't it be better to always return a pointer rather than a reference? the pointer may be `null` and the second overload would be dereferencing it

Comment: @AndyProwl: [Yakk](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1774667/yakk) did that. Thanks both of you. :-)

Comment: Are the converters non-member methods?

Comment: @Casey: That depends on you. If you make them non-members, say in some utility headers, then you can reuse them if you ever need it.

Comment: A great answer to not just this question but also a solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301330/determine-if-type-is-a-pointer-in-a-template-function

Comment: Not sure but what about smart pointer (unique_ptr, shared_ptr) ? I tried and apparently they are being passed as reference.

Comment: @Trung0246 smart pointer != pointer. Smart pointers are objects that wrap pointers, not actual pointers. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417635/10463454) for more info

Comment: Great answer, I would just add that one might find they needs overrides for const