# Class template with both pointer type and regular type

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I define a Node class with template for its value type

```
template<class T>
class Node {
  T val;
  public:
    Node (T & v) : val (v) {}
    ...
    void print() { cout << v << endl; }
}
```

Most times, the node value of interest will be an object class, say `class Foo`. In that case, use `Node<Foo *>` will be more convenient. But it could also be that the node will hold primitive time, say `int`. Then use `Node<int>` will suffice.

The problem is, some of the function may need to behave differently based on whether `T` is a pointer type or not. For example, `print` should `cout << *v` when it is and `cout << v` otherwise.

What I've tried is to define both:

```
template<class T>
class Node {
  T val;
  public:
    Node (T & v) : val (v) {}
    ...
    void print() { cout << v << endl; }
}

template<class T>
class Node<T*> {
  T* val;
  public:
    Node (T* v) : val (v) {}
    ...
    void print() { cout << *v << endl; }
}
```

It now can choose the appropriate definition based on whether it's `Node<int> or Node<int *>` But the problem become, the two definitions will share many code. I'm wondering  whether there's better way to achieve this.

Comment: Can you explain why you think Node<Foo*> would be more convenient than Node<Foo>? If this Node is being used as a tree-node for example, then Node<Foo>* would be a better solution

Comment: Foo are globally allocated/used objects. Only passing Foo* to the data field won't involve recreating the objects. I'm only saying the type T for Node, not Node itself.

Comment: Hi, did you solve that problem? I am in the same situation, where I want just different behave of destructor. Specially, if is parametr value, I just want to delete node, but if it is pointer, I want first delete that pointer and after that the node self.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this: [C++ template specialization, calling methods on types that could be pointers or references unambiguously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466620/c-template-specialization-calling-methods-on-types-that-could-be-pointers-or/14466705)

The same technique should work here, allowing you to deal with the `val` as a reference (or a pointer) uniformly in both cases.

[CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) may help reduce code duplication, allowing for common code for two specializations without any overhead, as well.

Note that ownership semantics get tricky when you sometimes use a pointer and sometimes an instance -- what is the lifetime of `val` if sometimes it is a pointer of an argument, and other times it is a copy of the argument, and how to you enforce it?

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is one more way of doing this. You should use type traits, they are evaluated at compile time. This is how you can modify.

```cpp
template<class T>
class Node {
  T val;
  public:
    Node (T & v) : val (v) {}
    ...
    void print() { 
      if(std::is_pointer<T>::value)
        cout << *v << endl;
      else
        cout << v << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, this is how I could solve it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename T> struct is_shared_ptr : std::false_type {};
template<typename T> struct is_shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<T>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
void is_shared(const T& t) {
    std::cout << is_shared_ptr<T>::value << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
T* to_ptr(T& obj) {
    std::cout << "Ref to Ptr" << std::endl;
    return &obj;
}

template<typename T>
T* to_ptr(std::shared_ptr<T> & obj) {
    std::cout << "SharedPtr to Ptr" << std::endl;
    return obj.get();
}

template<typename T>
T* to_ptr(T* obj) {
    std::cout << "Ptr to Ptr" << std::endl;
    return obj;
}

// This is my usecase: Depending on the type, `.` or `->` is needed.
// But the if T = shared_ptr<Text>, `->` did not work...
template<typename T>
void free_printsize(T t){
    auto t_ptr = to_ptr(t);
    t_ptr->printsize();
}

class Text{
    std::string text_;
public:
    Text(const std::string &t){ text_ = t; }
    void printsize() const{
        std::cout << "Size of '" << text_ << "': " << text_.size();
    }
};

int main()
{    
    std::cout << "Testing value object: ";
    Text test("Hello");    
    is_shared(test);
    free_printsize(test);

    std::cout << "\n\nTesting ptr: ";
    Text* test_ptr = &test;
    is_shared(test_ptr);
    free_printsize(test_ptr);

    std::cout << "\n\nTesting shared ptr: ";
    std::shared_ptr<Text> test_sp = std::make_shared<Text>("Hello");
    is_shared(test_sp);
    free_printsize(test_sp);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Testing value object: 0
Ref to Ptr
Size of 'Hello': 5
Testing ptr: 0
Ptr to Ptr
Size of 'Hello': 5
Testing shared ptr: 1
SharedPtr to Ptr
Size of 'Hello': 5
Process exited with code: 0
```