# Have a template parameter that can be pointer type or non-pointer type

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, c++11

Suppose I have something like:

```
template <class T>
void do_something(T t){
  pass_it_somewhere(t);
  t->do_something();
}
```

Now it would be useful that `T` is allowed to be a pointer- or a non-pointer type. Function `do_something(...)` can basically handle pointers and non-pointers, except for the `t->do_something()`. For pointers, I would need a `->` and for non-pointers, I would need a `.` to access members.

**Is there a way to make `T` accept pointers *and* non-pointers?**

Comment: While this question has some interesting answers, I eventually also found a great solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466620/c-template-specialization-calling-methods-on-types-that-could-be-pointers-or/14466705

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could create a dereference mechanism as below:

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<T>::value, std::remove_pointer_t<T>&> dereference(T& t) { 
  return *t; 
}

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer<T>::value, T&> dereference(T& t) {
  return t;
}
```

and use it in your function as:

```
template <class T>
void do_something(T t){
  pass_it_somewhere(dereference(t));
  dereference(t).do_something();
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f281c8905cccbcd1)

This way you'll have to do only with concrete versions of `T`.

Comment: I think that's the best answer since it results in very readable and concise code. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 9):

**Soultion 1**

Use template specialization:

```
template <class T>
void do_something(T t){
  pass_it_somewhere(t);
  t.do_something();
}

template <class T>
void do_something(T* t){
  pass_it_somewhere(t);    
  t->do_something();
}
```

**Solution 2**

Add a user-defined pointer operator in class T:

```
class A
{
public:
    void do_something() const {}        
    const A* operator->() const { return this; }
};

template <class T>
void do_something(T t){
  pass_it_somewhere(t);      
  t->do_something();
}
```

Comment: s/specialize/overload

Answer (score 3):

Yet another solution: tag dispatching.

```
namespace detail {
    struct tag_value {};
    struct tag_ptr {};

    template <bool T>  struct dispatch       { using type = tag_value; };
    template <>        struct dispatch<true> { using type = tag_ptr;   };

    template <class T>
    void do_call(T v, tag_value)
    {
      v.call();
    }

    template <class T>
    void do_call(T ptr, tag_ptr)
    {
       ptr->call();
    }
}
```

Then your function becomes:

```
template <class T>
void do_something(T unknown)
{
   do_call(unknown, 
                typename detail::dispatch<std::is_pointer<T>::value>::type{} );

   // found by ADL

}
```

---

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95b5f7450ec5d42b).