# Generic for loop for elementary and complex type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Suppose I have those two `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> v_int(1000);
std::vector<T> v_T(1000); // Where T is copy-costy type
```

if I need to loop through them (sepereatly) without the need for editing the items I may use:

```
for(const auto item:v_int){
    //...
}

for(const auto& item:v_T){ //Note &
    //...
}
```

Iterating using `const auto item:v_T` is too bad since a copy will be performed in each iteration. However, using `const auto& item:v_int` is not optimal but not that bad. So if I need a code that deal with both them I used to use `const auto& item:v`.

**Question**: Is there a generic way to write the for loop that will use the best declaration for both of them? Something like:

```
template <typename T>
void iterate(const std::vector<T> v){
    for(const auto/*&*/ item:v){ // activate & if T is not elementary type
         //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you would want to avoid references in cases where T is a primitive type?

Comment: Is this added complexity really worth the effort for using value rather than reference semantics for built-in types?

Comment: Why not use a normal iterator loop, and the problem evaporates.

Comment: I think you can use std::is_fundamental<T>::value. check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/580935/4635560

Comment: Have you tested to see that `const int&` is actually slower than `int`? I'd guess that a smart compiler would generate the same code for both.

Comment: Sorry for being late... I did not test it actually. I have just always read that it is better and I thought that it is the best practice always

Comment: @HumamHelfawi I think best practice is to write legible code and don't micro-optimise until you find a real performance issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this using the standard type traits:

```
template <typename T>
using select_type = std::conditional_t<std::is_fundamental<T>::value,
                                      const T, const T&>;

template <typename T>
void iterate(const std::vector<T> v){
    for(select_type<T> item:v){ // activate & if T is not elementary type
         //...
    }
}
```

However, I question the wisdom of doing this. It just clutters the code for something which is unlikely to make any difference.

Comment: [Boost call traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm) handles pointer, float, ...

Answer (score 4):

Use `auto&&` when you just don't care.  Use `auto const&` when you must guarantee it is not edited.

References are aliases, and in an immediate context like a loop are trivial to optimize out of existence, especially if the value is never modified.

There are some difficulties when a reference is passed over a compilation unit boundary to a function, which is why passing `int` by value instead of `const&` is advised sometimes, but that does not apply here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a specialist in `template` area but I think what bothers you is that in case of `char` the copy will copy only one byte while using `&` will copy `sizeof(char*)` bytes.

What comes to my mind is to use the `sizeof(T)`.

In this case you can use

```
if (sizeof(T) >= sizeof(void*))
     // use '&'
else
     // don't use '&'
```

since `sizeof` is evaluated in the compilation time, this `if` branch will be optimized out by the compiler.

Comment: interesting approach to determine if `&` is needed or not. By combining with TartanLlama answer, we can use : `template <typename T>
using select_type = std::conditional_t<sizeof(T) >= sizeof(void*),
                                      const T, const T&>;`

Comment: You'd probably want to check if the type is trivially copyable is well  if you went this route.

Comment: @TartanLlama if the size of the type is smaller than the pointer size then it must be "trivially copyable", am I missing anything here?...

Comment: @AlexLop. Not necessarily. For example, the type could have a single `char` member which represents a handle to some resource. The size would be very small, but copying could be very expensive if it had to do some processing with the handle. (a bit obscure, I know, but if we're being generic, we may as well be totally generic)

Comment: @TartanLlama Definitely obscure case but I agree, you solution is more generic. The C++11 introduced a bunch of new usable functions to improve template development. Since I deal very little with templates, your introduction of `std::is_fundamenta<>` was a "discovery" for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would just use const auto& for every case because the overhead is negligible unless you're needing to crunch some very large data sets in tight loops.

An approach to obtain what you want however might be to implement template specializations for your iterate method:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
void iterate(const std::vector<T>& v){
    for(const auto& item:v){
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
    }
}

template <>
void iterate(const std::vector<int>& v){
    for(const auto item:v){
         std::cout << "[" << item << "]" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> strings = { "foo", "bar" };
    std::vector<int> numbers = { 1, 2 };

    iterate(strings);
    iterate(numbers);
}
```

Note: you're more likely to see a performance hit from copy constructing your vectors into the iterate function :)

Comment: That's if there's any overhead at all.

Comment: But you have to implement specializations for every fundamental type.

Comment: What do you mean by your note? The vectors are taken by reference; no copies here.

Comment: The question's iterate method does not. I updated my example code to use references.

Comment: @Garf365: You could rather use tag dispatching depending on whether `is_fundamental<T>` and specialize thereby.

Comment: @black Yes, using SFINAE, but in this case, I prefer Tartan llama's answer

Comment: @Garf365 No, you don't need SFINAE. I wrote an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36917819/have-a-template-parameter-that-can-be-pointer-type-or-non-pointer-type/36918684#36918684), you'd just need to swap `is_pointer` with `is_fundamental`.

Comment: @black OK, I didn't think about this kind of design, using a second parameter as flag. Useful in case as your example. I will remember for future use ;) Here, I still prefer Tartan Llama's answer