# How do you decide on value vs reference for template methods

Tags: c++, templates, typename

If I have a template function like

```
template<typename T>
void doSomething(const T arg) {.....}
```

then I do not know ahead of time if T is a simple int or if it is a huge struct. If it is an int, passing by value makes sense, while the struct should be passed by reference.

How do I design a template function which works sensibly with both types of argument?

Comment: Won't your function be necessarily `inline` (since it is header only)? In this case, the compiler may optimise `const int&` arguments to `int`. You can (=should) test whether there is any measurable benefit from using plain values instead of `const` references.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic for loop for elementary and complex type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37272094/generic-for-loop-for-elementary-and-complex-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`boost::call_traits`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm) library has several helpers for stuff like this. In particular, `call_traits<T>::param_type`

> Defines a type that represents the "best" way to pass a parameter of type T to a function.

You use it like so:

```
template<typename T>
void doSomething(typename boost::call_traits<T>::param_type arg) {.....}
```

It basically works by specializing the class for speacial cases. So, e.g., your `int` case from the question is (indirectly) specialized to `int` (and not `int &`).

Comment: This is obviously useful for something like boost, but for most templates that people write in day-to-day work, I would say "don't sweat it".  The optimizer will probably deal with the different between `const int& arg` and `int arg` - given that templates are pretty much always inline.

Comment: @MartinBonner That makes sense. Also, "root of all evil" and that. Still, the question was asked.

Comment: @MartinBonner: How do you come to the assumption (or maybe fact) proposed by "given that templates are pretty much always inline"? Is that something to rely on?

Comment: @thokra: Yes, you can rely on that.  In general you have to define template functions and member functions in header files (not in separately compiled .cpp files).  The only exception is when you know all the types that you are going to instantiate the templates for (at which point the problem goes away).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're asking for a solution to a problem that only arises from a poor 'solution' to another problem. So, here I decide to answer your initial problem instead.

Since your template function will almost certainly have to be `inline`, most compilers will optimize the function call away and with it your problem. Thus, it may actually not matter what you use, but `T const&arg` is the more conservative.

So, before 'solving' this problem, you should test whether there is any measurable difference between the two options for a simple `int` (with production-style optimisation switched on).