# Compiler error trying to delete template type which is a pointer

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, compiler-errors

I'm new to C++ and I have the ambition to understand how templates work. So I have implemented a generic list `MyList` which may contain both built-in primitive types and pointers. In the `remove` function I want to distinguish pointer types and built-ins so I can delete the object behind the pointer but leave the built-ins untouched.

To distinguish the template types, which can be pointers or non-pointers, I wrote the following functions, which work fine:

```
// distinguish between pointer and non-pointer type of template variable
template<typename T> bool is_pointer(T t) {
    return false;
}

template<typename T> bool is_pointer(T* t) {
    return true;
}
```

In the list function `remove` the idea was to test for pointers and delete them in case. However, the delete statement does not compile:

```
template<typename T> void MyList<T>::remove() {
    ...
    if (is_pointer(temp->getContent())) {
        // delete object pointer points to
        T t = temp->getContent();
        cout << t;    // prints out address
        // delete t;  // produces compiler error (see below)
}
```

In the `main.cpp` I test the list class with various types, I call amongst others:

```
MyList<int> mylist;                // with type int
mylist.remove();
mylist.add(3);
// add and remove elements

MyList<string> mylist2;           // with type string
...

MyList<string*> mylist3;          // with type string*
mylist.add(new string("three")); 
mylist.remove();
```

When I comment out the statement `delete t;` I can verify that the control flow is correct: the if-statement is only entered for the `string*` example. However, if I uncomment the `delete` statement the compiler complains like that:

```
../mylist.h: In member function ‘void MyList<T>::remove() [with T = int]’:
../main.cpp:36:18:   instantiated from here
../mylist.h:124:6: error: type ‘int’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected pointer
../mylist.h: In member function ‘void MyList<T>::remove() [with T = std::basic_string<char>]’:
../main.cpp:71:18:   instantiated from here
../mylist.h:124:6: error: type ‘struct std::basic_string<char>’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected pointer
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

What is it that I don't see? I'm using the `delete` statement on pointers only but still I get these compiler errors. If I print out `t` in the if-statement it is a pointer address!

Comment: `T t` is not a pointer, what does `getContent()` return? Also, you are using the `void*` overload for `operator<<` which is why you are seeing the address.

Comment: Of course, you can't delete non-pointer types (that have no implicit conversion to an object pointer type). You can use a function `destroy` that has overloads for pointer and non-pointer types just like your `is_pointer`.

Comment: T t is not a pointer, so you cant delete it

Comment: (However, ) It might not be a good idea to store raw pointers and delete them later on, as you can easily form pointers to variables of automatic, static (or thread) storage duration. Just provide the non-pointer version and let the users use smart pointers instead.

Comment: Do you expect `if (false) delete 42;` to compile? That's essentially what you have.

Comment: `getContent()` returns a variable of type `T`.

Comment: Use smart pointers and avoid this headache-prone freakness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A template is a blueprint that the compiler uses to actually create types based on the use of the blueprint. When you use you template with `int` and `string*` the compiler will actually create two variations of `MyList`, replacing T with the actual type. The implementation that uses `int` for `T` is bogus, because deleting an int does not make sense. The actual code the compiler generates is

```
int t = temp->getContent();
cout << t;
delete t;
```

This is incorrect, as you could figure out.

Comment: I see, so it's not the compilation with the `string*` pointer that causes the compiler to complain but the compilation with the `int` and `string` types

Comment: @DyP So what I could use would be two `destroy` functions along the lines of the `is_pointer` functions with one that does nothing in case of built-ins and another that calls delete in case of pointers.

Comment: @Thomas789 Exactly, though, as I wrote in another comment, it might be best not do distinguish between them but rather let the user of the class use smart pointers instead. This also allows them to create `MyList`s of unmanaged raw pointers (for objects that are managed elsewhere).

Comment: @DyP I don't quite understand. The users should create smart pointers of the raw pointers but should supply the raw pointers to the list? But if the smart pointers are out of scope the objects will be deleted although the list still contains pointers to them?

Comment: @Thomas789 What I meant was that the users should have the choice to either use `MyList<smart_ptr<some_type>>` if `MyList` is to "manage" the lifetime of the stored `some_type` objects, and `MyList<some_type*>` if `MyList` shall not manage the lifetime of the pointed-to objects.

Comment: Yup: I'd hate it if `MyList<const char*>` would try to call `delete` on a string literal. Even if you knew that a pointer should be deleted, you wouldn't know whether to do that with `delete` or `delete[]`. So, just destroy each element of the list, and let its destructor handle anything else that's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you instantiate the template with `T = int`, you get:

```
void MyList::remove() {
    if (false) {
        T t = temp->getContent();
        cout << t;
        delete t;
    }
}
```

Even if the code block is never executed, it must be syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use C++ 11 type_traits and auto_ptr like this

```
#include <type_traits>
template<typename T> void MyList<T>::remove() {
    ...
    if (is_pointer(T)) {
        // delete object pointer points to
        T t = temp->getContent();
        cout << t;    // prints out address
        auto_ptr tempobj(T);
}
```

Also look at this [Determine if Type is a pointer in a template function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301330/determine-if-type-is-a-pointer-in-a-template-function) that could be useful incase your compiler is not C++ 11 compliant.

Thanks
Niraj Rathi

Comment: Doesn't help, the code will still be compiled for all instantiations. You'd need `enable_if` or something to prevent it from compiling invalid expressions.

Comment: Angew is right, but thanks anyway, it's a good idea for me to switch to C++11

Comment: edited to use auto_ptr so now delete will happen inside auto_ptr.

Comment: isn't auto_ptr deprecated in c++11?

Comment: Yes, but more importantly, it would need a type argument. And that can't be `auto_ptr<T>`, because that would declare a smart pointer to a pointer. (since we're thinking about the case where T itself is a pointer)